# How can I add nginx rewrite url+last_part with different_url+last_part?

Tags: regex, nginx, server, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite an nginx rewrite rule, but cant figure out how to do it.

This is my example URL:

```
cdn.example.com/public/storage/upload/images/1/2/3/4.jpg
cdn.example.com/public/storage/upload/images/1/2/3.jpg
```

I want to convert it to

```
cdn.example.com/storage/app/public/upload/images/1/2/3/4.jpg
cdn.example.com/storage/app/public/upload/images/1/2/3.jpg
```

I am not sure how can I just add `storage/app/` in front of the original URL and remove the `storage` after `public` from the original URL?

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/public/storage(/upload/images/.*)$ /storage/app/public$1 redirect;`

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be:

```
/public/storage/ /storage/app/public/
```

Assuming /public/storage/ does not appear anywhere else. Otherwise, include the domain name as well. If 'storage' is a pattern, then

```
/public/([a-z]+)/ /$1/app/public/
```